# postgres how to query ltree to match first two labels

Tags: postgresql

I have a table called wbs with the field wbs_number.

wbs_number is a ltree field.

The following records are in the table

```
ABC123.111
ABC123.112
ABC123.111.0001
ABC123.111.0002
ABC123.111.0003
ABC123.112.0001
ABC123.112.0002
ABC123.112.0003
```

I want a query to only fetch records with only two labels. Means I want the result to be ABC123.111, and ABC123.112

I got a syntax error with this query

```
SELECT wbs_number FROM wbs WHERE wbs_number @ 'ABC*.*';
```

My postgres is version 10.3 and I have checked that ltree extension is installed when I run `select * from pg_available_extensions;`

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is

`select wbs_number from wbs where path ~ 'ABC*.*{1}';`

Here is the [link](https://rextester.com/DPRDIC96440)

You can go through this [article](https://leopard.in.ua/2013/09/02/postgresql-ltree) to learn more.

Comment: Thanks! your answer led me to the exact query I need so I changed your answer

Answer (score -1):

Many solutions…

```
WHERE LENGTH(path) = 10

WHERE path NOT LIKE '%.%.%'
```